# C# WinForms/WPF: Есть ли решения вроде DevExpress и Telerik, но предназначенные не для Enterprise, а мелких проектов и ускоряющие их создание?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, devexpress, telerik

Попался мне мощный ПК с Windows 10 и VS 2017.
Решил воспользоваться случаем, посмотреть библиотеки.

Сперва поставил на него демо-версию Telerik для WPF.
Посмотрел, какие есть шаблоны проектов, контролы для панели элементов и попросту классы.

Удалил, поставил DevExpress.
Осматриваю его по тем же самым критериям...
...И ощущаю дежавю.
Шаблоны проектов - как будто скопированы у Telerik: либо Blank, либо Word inspired (в стиле Word с лентой a.k.a. Ribbon UI), и по большому счету это все. (Есть еще Excel inspired и пара других вариаций с лентой, но в целом ничего нового)

То же самое с контролами и классами.
Все это - тоже как под копирку. Схема такова:

- Грид. Хороший такой грид. В DevExpress это прям центр и гордость. Сюда же - прочее для работы с БД в "формате" Enterprise.
- Theme, skin, style, L&F, названия могут быть разными, суть - одна: это готовый дизайн для окна, обычно в стиле Material. Ну, и возможность применять кастомные скины. Все это обязательно включает в себя целую реализацию Ribbon, это наверно вторая по объему часть их работы (после грида).
- Что-то для веб-сервисов, опять же в "формате" Enterprise.
- ...И очень небольшое количество "общих" полезных вещей, вроде PasswordBox с кнопкой "глаз", или TextBox сразу с готовым Label (в готовом удобном контейнере), или наследник класса Window, в котором уже есть Alert(), Prompt() и Confirm(), чтобы сэкономить время на печатании "MessageBox-точка-таб".

**В Enteprise я не работаю.
Приложения для Windows пишу только на заказ с бюджетом до 50-100к.
С широкой аудиторией на Windows не работаю и не собираюсь, потому что у Microsoft нет маркета (платформа UWP не в счет, ей еще лет 10 надо для развития - или наоборот для смерти, вслед за WP).
Хотел бы писать именно эти приложения - быстрее.**

**Поэтому по большому счету, мне нужно только последнее. А его там - 5%**, не больше. Тащить ради этого целую библиотеку - это проще самому написать. А если покупать лицензию за 60.000 руб - то и вовсе молчу.

**Базы данных - нужны не в каждом проекте.
И нужны не супер-навороченные гриды и UI**, а например хорошая ORM для SQLite.
А если не для SQLite, а для Access или SQL server - то **нужна не библиотека, а генератор кода**. Чтобы быстро писать дипломы и курсачи. На библиотеке едва ли разрешат их писать.
Еще нужны **хорошие автоматизированные инструменты для Settings**. А то когда в приложении 120 настроек, включая вложенные, то вручную писать код, который их все положит в JSON и сохранит (а потом код, который их оттуда загрузит обратно по контролам) - не здорово.

**По веб-сервисам - HTTP для C# мне нужно только клиентское. Уже есть RestSharp и xNet. Они устраивают, лучше них только библиотека с интеграцией со сниффером (например с Fiddler'ом от того же Telerik)** - чтобы писать боты: прямо из сниффера брать тело запроса и заголовки и автоматом в код. **Насчет TCP - нужна легкая библиотека и для клиента и для сервера**, реализующая прикладной двусторонний протокол с надежной связью на базе TCP, **но без ASP.NET** как у SignalR.

Да, часть всего перечисленного тоже есть, где-то в недрах DX/Telerik.
Замечу, что **DevExpress для меня ближе, чем Telerik.**
Но, все равно, этого мало (а изменить так просто нельзя, код закрыт), и неохота тащить остальные 70-90%, и оплачивать их.

Какие есть альтернативы ближе к моей ситуации?
Неужели все подобные решения создавались и создаются только товарищами из Enterprise для таких же?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61652/discussion-on-question-by-rou1997-c-winforms-wpf-----devexpr).